Old children's book involving American Football and aliens
I don't recall much about the book, other than a character named Brian Broome, and aliens, and getting beamed up to space.
A kids team was beamed up to some planet where they were obsessed with American football. The way the aliens fought wars was via football. They had a moon that orbited between the planets in a figure 8 and when it was exactly in the middle they played the game.
I probably read it in the 1980's or 1990's. It has a Gordon Korman feeling to it, but I don't believe it was written by him

Are we talking American football or British football here?

American football. A kids team was beamed up to some planet where they were obsessed with football. The way the aliens fought wars was via football. They had a moon that orbited between the planets in a figure 8 and when it was exactly in the middle they played the game.
